# Java - date time is always -1h from the local time

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone

I have a 'simple' problem with Java and dates. I thought it was simple but I don't understand how to solve it ! I have try a lot of things. Here is the problem.

I save a date in my postgres sql database like this.

```
user.setCreationDate(Timestamp.valueOf((LocalDateTime.now())));
```

this date is store with one hour less than the real hour here.
When I want to use it, I would like to get in database and add the UTC +1 of my local zone.

I try this but always get the date -1h...

```
OffsetDateTime myNewDate = bddDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime()
```

Do you have an idea of how just get the local timezone exact hour ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Presumably related to either timezone or daylight savings. I'd use `Timestamp.from(Instant.now())`, might make a difference.

Comment: Does it answer your question? [Converting date to timestamp with timezone in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352082/converting-date-to-timestamp-with-timezone-in-java)

Comment: Does it answer your question? [Datetime behind an hour after insertion. Daylight savings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812572/datetime-behind-an-hour-after-insertion-daylight-savings/65813340)